# Testing Rack Routing Using rSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I have a rule in my routes.rb:

```
constraints AssetRestrictor do
  match '*seopath' => SeoDispatcher
end
```

Then in lib/seo_dispatcher.rb, I have this:

```
class SeoDispatcher
  AD_KEY = "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"

  def self.call(env)
    seopath = env[AD_KEY][:seopath]

    if seopath
      params = seopath.split('/')           # get array of path components
      env[AD_KEY][:id] = params.last        # the real page name is the last element
      env[AD_KEY][:category] = params.first if params.length > 1
    end

    Rails.logger.debug "routing to show #{env[AD_KEY]}"
    PagesController.action(:show).call(env)
    # TODO error handling for invalid paths
  end
end

class AssetRestrictor
  EXCEPTION_FILES = ['javascripts', 'stylesheets', 'autodiscover']
  def self.matches?(request)
    return false if request.method == 'POST'  # no post requests are SEO-ed
    EXCEPTION_FILES.each do |ex|
      return false if request.url.include?(ex)
    end
    true
  end
end
```

And basically, the whole thing works. The idea is to peel off the last path component and match it to the slug for a page. SEO people tell me this is the cool way to trick search engines into ranking you higher.

My snarky comments aside, I'm having trouble writing a test in rSpec that exercises this code. My first shot at it was:

```
describe SeoDispatcher do
  it "routes /insurance/charters-and-guides/how-to-buy-charter-boat-insurance to pages#show :id => how-to-buy-charter-boat-insurance" do
    { :get => "/insurance/charters-and-guides/how-to-buy-charter-boat-insurance"}.should route_to(
      :controller => 'pages',
      :action     => 'show',
      :id         => 'how-to-buy-charter-boat-insurance'
    )
  end
end
```

But this simply doesn't exercise the Rack dispatch code. Does anyone know how one would (than cuking it) exercise the code? I really want to bring the parameters in from Rack instead of just doing `SeoDispatcher.call({"action_dispatch.request.path_parameters" => {:seopath => "/foo/bar"}})`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, answered my own question. Request spec:

```
describe SeoDispatcher do
  describe "seo parsing" do
    it "GET /insurance/charters-and-guides/how-to-buy-charter-boat-insurance displays how-to-buy-charter-boat-insurance (3-part path)" do
      p = Page.make(:title => "how-to-buy-charter-boat-insurance")
      p.save
      get "/insurance/charters-and-guides/how-to-buy-charter-boat-insurance"
      request.path.should == "/insurance/charters-and-guides/how-to-buy-charter-boat-insurance"
      assigns[:page].slug.should == "how-to-buy-charter-boat-insurance"
    end

    it "GET /insurance/charters-and-guides displays guides (2-part path)" do
      p = Page.make(:title => "charters and guides")
      p.save
      get "/insurance/charters-and-guides"
      request.path.should == "/insurance/charters-and-guides"
      assigns[:page].slug.should == "charters-and-guides"
    end

    it "GET /insurance displays insurance (1-part path)" do
      p = Page.make(:title => "insurance")
      p.save
      get "/insurance"
      request.path.should == "/insurance"
      assigns[:page].slug.should == "insurance"
    end
  end
end
```

If anyone knows a better way, feel free to let me know!